# Android: Runtime error: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4198ccf8)

Tags: android

I have created a form and am getting the following error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.*****.******, PID: 15427
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view
        at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild(ViewGroup.java:4779)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(ViewGroup.java:4713)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.scrollToRectOrFocus(ViewRootImpl.java:3017)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2641)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2587)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2210)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The problem is the app will work half of the time and crash at other times, as in, being able to reproduce the same crash is not possible. I understand that its a runtime error; so how should I go about it?